# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.1.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I would to integrate GDPR SDK i always get this error, what i can do to reslove this error

> Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.1.0

**build.gradle (module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.artdevstudio.currencyconverter"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}




android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    compile 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.3'

    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Prefs:1.1'


}
```

**build.gradle (project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        maven  {
            url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the [consent SDK](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android) is 1.0.6, not 1.1.0. Try using this instead:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `compile` with `implementation` under the dependencies section.